# What does setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) do more exactly?

Tags: php, error-handling, setattribute

As the title says, i tried to understand the concept but it seems like with it or without it the result its the same. I tried to look into php manual and i  kind of understand what says but  in practice its just seems the result is the same.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manual **also** [says](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-errors) that

> PDO::__construct() throws a PDOException if the attempt to connect to the requested database fails.

This is your case exactly. And it has **nothing** to do with `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

To test `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` - **properly** connect to an **existing** database and run an **invalid** query.

Comment: Thank you , i tested it on a query with and without setattrib and now i can see the difference .

Comment: PDO error modes as a reference https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php